# what's the fastest way for switches the high voltage?

Tags: relay, high-voltage

i want to use relay for project that the electricity will turn on and off about five times per second ...

30 volt 5 ampere DC i think will work for the project , and the load is Resistive ...

is there any relay that can support that rate .. ?

i think the normal relay won't work but what's the solution ?

totaly what's the best way to switch the high voltage with highest speed and accurate ..?

it's too important for me to switch several times on or off in one second ...

anyone can help me please ??

Comment: (1) "*... the high voltage ...*" How high? Use numbers. (2) What current? (Use numbers.) (3) AC or DC? (4) What is the load? Resistive, inductive or capacitive? Hit the [edit] link below your question.

Comment: have you looked at solid state relays?

Comment: You can never design any switch unless you specify load resistance + reactance and voltage , current limits.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 i edit the question

Comment: You didn't answer number (4).

Comment: @Transistor it's Resistive

Answer (score 2):

Use a solid-state relay (SSR) DC type.

[image]

*Figure 1. A DC SSR features optical isolation between the input and the output. Image source: [Phidgets.com](https://www.phidgets.com/docs/Solid_State_Relay_Primer).*

The control input is usually switched by 3 - 30 V DC and will require maybe 20 mA.

You need to select one that can handle the required output voltage and current. The external diode is only required on inductive loads.

---

By the way, 30 V isn't considered a high voltage in most applications.

Comment: tnx for answer ...

Comment: actually yes 30 volt isnt' high voltage , but when i want to post the question i was curious that how switch the high voltage fast ...